# How to fill an array with 10 even integers following some user provided integer?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Basically I just want to take the provided integer and fill the array with the 10 even integers that come after the input integer. For example, if the user inputs 10 then the resulting array would be `{12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30}`. The current code I am using is below, and it produces an array of the correct magnitude but filled entirely with zeros (`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`).

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrays {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] array = new int[10];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter starting number: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i > number; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                array[i] = i;
            }
        }

        for(int element: array) {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I generate the desired output array containing 10 even integers?

Comment: so your problem is that "i > number" is never true. please next time specify the issue you're facing when asking questions :).

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? As of right now, it won't even enter that for loop because of your condition `i > number`.

Comment: @adam-o-hanlon Please accept an answer (not necessarily mine)for the question if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer which includes graceful failure for invalid input types and overflows of the `int` type maximum boundary. It also zero fills the result array upon detection of a failure to prevent an intermediate state from leaking.

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrays {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] array = new int[10];
        int number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter starting number: ");


        try{
            number = sc.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input detected - Not an integer");
            System.exit(0);
        }       

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {

            if(number % 2 == 0){
                array[i] = (number + 2) + (2 * i);
            }else{
                array[i] = (number + 1) + (2 * i);
            }

            if(number > array[i]){
                System.out.println("Invalid input detected - overflow of type int!");
                Arrays.fill(array, 0);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add 10 numbers, you'll want to do something like

`for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)`

Which loops 10 times with `i` having the value of 0, 1, 2, ... 9. In the loop you can do something like `array[i] = next_even_number+i*2;` where `next_even_number` is the next even number after the user input to add the numbers.

Answer (score -2):

The problem in your case is that `for(int i = 0; i > number; i++)` means
"do something as long as the 'i' is greater than number, so it will not even enter the loop as the i starts from 0 and the input number you put is greater than 0. Instead of this, try to do the following

```
int counter = 0;
int num = number;
while(counter < 10){
  num++;
  if(num%2 == 0){
     array[counter] = num;
     counter++;
  }
}
```

Use a while loop which will consider the amount of numbers greater than your input that are even (num%2==0) and assign to your array in the position of the current counter

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation. User is here to learn, not be given code